# How can I modify a value before it is shown in a databound Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, repeater, rowdatabound

I am databinding a repeater some text and a datetime(Respond By).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" OnItemDataBound="repeaterDatabound" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
              <td>
                  <b>Respond By</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <%#Eval("RespondBy")%>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

Here I want to change the datatime before I display it on the screen, I want to do a `rowdatabound` similar to the one below. How can I do that for a repeater. Or is there anyother way of adding value(3Hrs) to Respond by dateTime before displaying it to users.

```
   protected void repeaterDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RespondBy")), out Respond);
        }
    }
```

I cant add 3hrs in the client side, the no of hours I have to add is different for each users,

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you trying to do? Is it nothing that could be accomplished with formatting or an addtional column in the datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do following in aspx file.

```
 ((DateTime)Eval("RespondBy")).AddHours(3)
```

Or add a label/literal in aspx instead of `<%#Eval("RespondBy")%>` and use it in ItemDataBound

Answer (score 0):

You could either change your `<%#Eval("RespondBy)%>` to some server control, a `<asp:Literal>` for example, then update the value of this in your `ItemDataBound` method.

Or you could use some inline code

```
<%#((DateTime) Eval("RespondBy")).AddHours(3).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")%>
```

Or you could produce a public function which you can then reuse in the future.

```
public static string RespondByDate(DateTime theDate){
    return theDate.AddHours(3).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
}
```